# MYSQL QUERY SHOW COLUMNS LIMIT

Tags: mysql

```
 SHOW COLUMNS FROM ranks LIMIT 3,6
```

Display error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 3,6' at line 1

I googled this problem and I don't found nothing to help.

Is this a bug of MySql ?

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html   there is no "limit" support for "show columns".

Comment: You can't do this. You _can_ however query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `LIMIT clause` for [***SHOW COLUMNS Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html).

Though you can use `WHERE` clause. For an eg:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM ranks WHERE Field NOT IN ('id', 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot use `LIMIT clause` for [SHOW COLUMNS Syntax]
> (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html).

> Though you can use WHERE clause. For an eg:
>
> `SHOW COLUMNS FROM ranks WHERE Field NOT IN ('id', 'name');`

Although the above answer is correct

It's not the best answer as it would require you to specify the columns you don't need wherein [@geomo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156389/geomo) wants to include the first 10 columns, which is why I would like to update this answer.

As stated by [@Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358679/wrikken) you can query the information_schema.columns table to achieve a similar effect.

The code for the same would be :

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT, IS_NULLABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table' LIMIT 10;
```

In this query, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table contains metadata about the columns in all the tables and views in the current database. The `WHERE` clause restricts the results to the columns in the `my_table` table, and the `LIMIT` clause limits the output to the first 10 rows returned by the query.